# The quickindex option is not working with xepersian package

Tags: xetex, errors, memoir, right-to-left, bidi

I have installed TeXLive 2010 on Ubuntu 10.10,
when I try to compile a LaTeX file such as:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[Kashida,quickindex]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{Yas}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Junicode}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{ParsiDigits}
\begin{document}
‫این فقط یک آزمایش است‬.\index{آزمایش}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

using `xelatex --shell-escape filename.tex`,
the following error message appeared:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@nil 

l.39 \settextfont
                 [Scale=1]{Yas}%{Scheherazade}
```

what is the meaning of the error and what should I do to solve that?

In addition, the error does not appear, when I change the **documentclass** by **article**!

**I should mention that the quickindex option working by the latest version of xepersian that can be obtained from ctan, also it depend on latest version of fontspec and so on. thus you should update your TeXLive, as I did!**

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows your problem allowing the reader to reproduce and to fix it.

Comment: @hassan: Please post a minimal example, starting `\begin{document}`. You can mark up code using the `101010` button in the editor.

Comment: @Joseph: Shouldn't it start with `\documentclass{<something>}` to make sure the full preamble is included?

Comment: @Jake. Oops, yes indeed it should!

Comment: @Joseph,@Jake,@Stefan: the minimal example and additional details added.

Comment: For me it already complains about the `quickindex` option.

Comment: @Caramdir: @Others, I should mention that the quickindex option working by the latest version of xepersian that can be obtained from ctan, also it depend on latest version of fontspec and so on. thus you should update your TeXLive, as I did!

Comment: I did (today). The version in TL2010 is 1.1.0β1.2 form Dec 6. Do you get the same error when removing `quickindex`?

Comment: @hassan. As this only shows up with the latest `xepersian` release, I'd say it's probably a bug in the package. I'd report it _via_ the BitBucket site listed in the documentation.

Comment: I can cut the example down further, to `\documentclass{memoir} \usepackage[quickindex]{xepersian} \AnythingYouLike`, with the error coming at the end of package loading for `xepersian`.

Comment: @Caramdir: No I didn't, the error was not shown when the `quickindex` option removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is actually intended to behave this way. quickindex option does not support memoir class yet and the error that you get is on purpose. quickindex option is added in v1.1.0 of xepersian and it is available on CTAN now. (at least on dante). I just uploaded it yesterday to dante.

Comment: Perhaps `\@ifclassloaded{memoir}{\PackageError{xepersian}{Memoir is not supported!}{}}{}` would be a good idea, then.

Comment: Ok, I got where I messed it up. I forgot about third argument of \PackageError. Many thanks for this. I will upload the corrected version tonight.